# Multiple useEffect not working as expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
useEffect(() => {
    debugger;
}, [filter]);

// eslint-disable-next-line
useEffect(async () => {
    if (parseInt(localStorage.getItem("lastFetchTime")) + 8640000 > Date.now()) {
        setRecipeList(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("recipeList")));
        setIsLoading(false);
    } else {
        await fetch('https://api.spoonacular.com/recipes/random?number=20&apiKey=3c6b5aedfaf34bb899d1751ea2feb1b2')
                        .then((resp) => resp.json())
                        .then((data) => {
        setRecipeList(data.recipes);
        setIsLoading(false);
        localStorage.setItem("recipeList", JSON.stringify(data.recipes));
        localStorage.setItem("lastFetchTime", Date.now());
    })
    }
}, []);
```

I have these 2 useEffect in my program, the first one, with the listener is not being called even if the filter is changed. But it works if I remove the [] from the 2nd useEffect and the 2nd one runs on loop so I cant use it like that. I saw multiple forums, all of which suggests this should work.

Comment: what is `filter`?

Comment: @Yousaf just a js object 

{"vegan":true,"vegetarian":true,"glutenFree":true,"dairyFree":true,"time":"180"}

Comment: How do you update it? Also don't mix `async-await` syntax with promise chaining; remove the `then()` method calls and just `await` `fetch(...)` and `resp.json()`.

Answer (score 0):

useEffect cannot be async. If you want to call an async function in useEffect() you need to do it like this:

**EDIT: this is the complete useEffect**

```
  useEffect(() => {
    async function getData() {
      if (
        parseInt(localStorage.getItem("lastFetchTime")) + 8640000 >
        Date.now()
      ) {
        setRecipeList(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("recipeList")));
        setIsLoading(false);
      } else {
        const res = await fetch(
          "https://api.spoonacular.com/recipes/random?number=20&apiKey=3c6b5aedfaf34bb899d1751ea2feb1b2"
        );

        const data = await res.json();
        setRecipeList(data.recipes);
        setIsLoading(false);
        localStorage.setItem("recipeList", JSON.stringify(data.recipes));
        localStorage.setItem("lastFetchTime", Date.now());
      }
    }
    getData();
  }, []);
```

I tested it and it worked as expected (I console.log() in the other useEffect())

Comment: Removed async await part, still doesn't work

Comment: did you try to put `recipeList` and `isLoading` into the dependency array of the second useEffect?

Comment: @PixAff I guess, Harsh just wants to run 2nd useEffect only once.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

const sleep = (ms: number) => new Promise(
  resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve('Resolved'), ms));

function App() {
  const [filter, setFilter] = useState({ count: 0 });
  const [get, set] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('Here');
  }, [filter]);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function myFunction() {
      const res = await sleep(5000)
      .then(res => console.log(res));
      setFilter({ ...filter, count: filter.count + 1 });
    }
    myFunction();
  }, [get]);
  return (
    <div>
      <p>App {get}</p>
      <button onClick={() => set((get: number) => get + 1)}>
        Click
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

This minor snippet to be working for me as expected.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with the useEffect. It's a bullet proof. But you make sure the following things:

Is `filter` updated during the component did mount?
The debugger will show up if you have open developer tool.

Is`filter` updated during the component did update?
The debugger won't show up.

To make sure when`filter` is updated, use another effect hook but this time without dependency array.

```
useEffect(()=>{
  console.log(filter) // analyze in the console
})
```

And if the value is updated during the update then you don't need to use dependency array but check the changes inside the effect hook by using some state for that as filter is coming from the update (props).

Comment: I guess, you are only talking about the first useEffect? Since there is something wrong with the second one (see my answer about useEffect and async functions)

Answer (score 0):

```
import { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from "react";

function App() {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [filter, setRecipeList] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    // debugger;
  }, [filter]);

  // eslint-disable-next-line
  const fetchData = useCallback(async () => {
    if (
      parseInt(localStorage.getItem("lastFetchTime")) + 8640000 >
      Date.now()
    ) {
      setRecipeList(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("recipeList")));
      setIsLoading(false);
    } else {
      const data = await fetch(
        "https://api.spoonacular.com/recipes/random?number=20&apiKey=3c6b5aedfaf34bb899d1751ea2feb1b2"
      ).then((resp) => resp.json());

      setRecipeList(data.recipes);
      setIsLoading(false);
      localStorage.setItem("recipeList", JSON.stringify(data.recipes));
      localStorage.setItem("lastFetchTime", Date.now());
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    fetchData();
  }, [fetchData]);

  return (
    <div>
      <span>{isLoading ? "loading" : "loaded!"}</span>
      {!isLoading && filter && <div>filter size:{filter.length}</div>}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I think it will work properly.
Thanks.